# DocuSign SAML SSO Developer Account

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to get my DocuSign developer account enabled with the SAML SSO option? I've contacted normal support and they told me to post here to see if the feature can be enabled on my account.

Answer (score 0):

Jamie, I am sorry but you got wrong instructions from maybe an inexperienced Customer Service person.  To configure SAML/SSO we need to get your PII and your account information.  This is not a good forum for that.  Please reach back to your Account Manager or Solution Engineer and they will help you.